# Losing the eventMouseout call in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, mouseout

When a user hovers over an event in the FullCalendar, I execute this code in the eventMouseover

```
eventMouseover: function (event) {
  event._title = event.title;
  event.title = "Click to Delete"
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", event);
},
```

All it does is store the original title, and then change it to the delete text. Then it tells the calendar to update the event so it will show the updated title.

Then in the eventMouseout event, I want to reset the title back to what it use to be.

```
eventMouseout: function (event) {
  event.title = event._title;
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", event);
},
```

The problem is that with the updateEvent call in the mouseover event, the mouseout event will never fire. If I put an alert in the mouseout event, it won't fire unless I comment out the updateEvent line in mouseover.. I'm guessing it has something to do with how FullCalendar updates an existing event, but I'm not fluent enough in jQuery to really tell why this happening.

Any ideas on how to get around this? I know there are alternatives to trying to alter the event title in order to display the text, but I'd prefer to do it this way rather than using something like a tooltip plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is actually a bug resulting from an internal optimization in fullcalendar. can you add this to the issue tracker please?

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list

thanks!

Comment: I've entered the issue. http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=829 Thanks for the answer.